# How do I generate a desktop bridge package in VS2017 without MSB4044 error

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have an ATL C++ project I want to add to the windows store.
I followed the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net
But when I go to build my appx package by right clicking on the project, I get an error:

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets(179,5): error MSB4044: The "GenerateDesktopBridgeAppxManifest" task was not given a value for the required parameter "EntryPointExe".

I added a reference to my project as in the application section, and set it as the entrypoint.  However, the tick box doesn't seem to stay applied, even though the project name shows up in bold below Applications.

Inside the Package.appxmanifest this is under applications:

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">...
```

Should the macros have been substituted at some point?

I also tried by using the project under the C++ section instead of C# as shown in the first instructions, but also got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my problem was caused by a different name being used for the output of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and had me searching for some time for a solution to the error which was a total waste of time. This false error occurs when there is actually "real errors" in your project that are not showing. I closed and reopened VS and finally saw the real errors and once I fixed them this false error went away and everything built.

FYI: This happened to me again and reopening VS still did not show the errors. I had to build the offending project and then go to the Output Window to find the error as nothing was listed in the Errors Window.